# How to call a functional method from one react functional component to another react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component

I have written two components **EnrolmentForm.js** & **Verhoff.js**. Codes are written as mentioned below.

I want to call **verify function** "from Verhoff.js component into the EnrolmentForm.js component". how can i do that?

I tried to find the solution everywhere but got nothing. Your help is appreciated.

**1.) EnrolmentForm.js**

```
function EnrolmentForm() {
  return (
    <div>
            <div className="container mt-2">             
                    <label>Aadhar Number : </label>
                    <input
                      className="input-group form-control"
                      type="password"
                      name="aadharnumber"
                    />
                  </div>
                    </div>
)}
```

**2.) Verhoff.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Verhoff() {

     const [aadharValue, setAadharValue] = useState("");
     const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")
   
//multiplication table d
var d = [ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5 ],
        [ 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6 ], [ 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7 ],
        [ 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1 ],
        [ 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2 ], [ 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3 ],
        [ 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4 ], [ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ] ];

// permutation table p
var p = [ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ], [ 1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4 ],
        [ 5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2 ], [ 8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7 ],
        [ 9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0 ], [ 4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1 ],
        [ 2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5 ], [ 7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8 ] ];

// inverse table inv
var inv = [ 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ];

// converts string or number to an array and inverts it
const invArray=(array)=> {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object Number]") {
        array = String(array);
        console.log(array, "!!!");
    }
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) == "[object String]") {
        array = array.split("").map(Number);
        console.log(array, "!!!")

    }
    return array.reverse();
};

// generates checksum
const generate=(array)=> {
    console.log("in generate")

    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = array.reverse();

    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]]);
        c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];

    }
    return inv[c];
};

// validates checksum
const validate=(array)=> {

    var c = 0;
    var invertedArray = invArray(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
        c = d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
    }

    return (c === 0);
};


const verify=(e)=>
  {
    setErrorMessage("");
      setAadharValue(e.target.value);
      console.log(aadharValue);
      if(e.target.value.length === 12)
      {
        var aadhaarArray = e.target.value.split('');
        var toCheckChecksum = aadhaarArray.pop();
        console.log(toCheckChecksum);
        if(generate(aadhaarArray) == toCheckChecksum)
        {
            setErrorMessage("valid ");
        }
        else{
            setErrorMessage("invalid");
        }
    }
  };
  
}
export default Verhoff;
```

Comment: the really simple answer is "you can't", since one is in the scope of a function so can't be accessed outside. (And it accesses internal variables of that function so you can't just extract it from it's place.) More helpfully: why do you want to call this function in another component? It's not clear what the connection is between them? In general, depending on your intention, you either want to pass a function as a prop from one component to another, or make some sort of custom hook to share behaviour between unrelated components.

Comment: i have made one validation component which has different functional methods. So, i will need it's functions in some of the other components for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an imperativeHandle, but you'd be better off refactoring the code so those methods aren't baked into the render function.

See also: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle