# Issue in ReactJs function calling between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component

**Problem:-**
I have written a function named "*getData()*" in "App.js" and i am able to call it in "User.js". Code is written below.

But, What if i have written that *"getdata()"* function in "User.js" and i have to call it in "App.js". How can i do that? i am not able to do so..
please guide me.

**App.js**

```
import User from './User'
function App() {
  function getData() {
    alert("Hello from app component")
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <User data={getData}/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App:
```

**User.js**

```
function User(props) {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>User Component</h1>
                <button onClick={props.data}> Call Function</button>
            </div>
    export default User;
```

Comment: You shouldn't. It is best practice to decouple logic like `getData` from your UI code. Put the function in a seperate file and import it

Comment: How exactly i can import it? just like another component? i didn't get it. Please explain.

Comment: Put the function in a seperate file and export it, just like you did with your User and App component. You can then use the import statement like you did in App.js, when you imported the user component.

Comment: Read about the import and export statements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: It is better to use redux for sharing values between components

Comment: I have one "Validation.js" component in which i have written Verhoff algorithm's methods in it . So, as per the need in other component, i want to call required function from "Validation.js" component. This is the link where i had mentioned the exact scenario. Please check and guide me if you can.   Link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668495/how-to-call-a-functional-method-from-one-react-functional-component-to-another-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***App.js***

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import User from './User';

function App() {
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <User ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={() => childRef.current.getData()}>Call Function</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

***User.js***

```
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const User = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getData() {
      alert('Hello from user component');
    },
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Component</h1>
    </div>
  );
});
export default User;
```